# Add a file upload field

Tags: plugins, uploads

I am building a plugin which has a file upload field in it's settings page. The files should not be image files but should be .doc, .txt etc. Struggling with the code for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Edit 1:
Here is the code -

```
$options = get_option('nn_sub_general_options');
if(!isset($options['nn_file_uploader'])) $options['nn_file_uploader'] = '';
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
echo "<form method='post' action='options.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='nn_sub_general_options[nn_file_uploader]' id='nn_sub_general_options[nn_file_uploader]' /></form>";
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['nn_sub_general_options[nn_file_uploader]'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
```

There seems to be some problem with the 3rd last line of the code as it gives me an Undefined index error there

Comment: An example of the code you have tried is very wellcome to help you in the best way.

Answer (score 1):

First do a `var_dump` on the `$_FILES` variable to check if the array key you are using is the correct one, and you should never just grab a variable that comes from user input and just use it, try doing a `isset` or `empty` before you use the variable.

After you found what is the key you will use [`wp_check_filetype`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_filetype) because it will give safer data about the file, you will have to do 2 `in_array` to check if both the mimetype of the file and the extension belongs to the set you are allowing the user to upload, if not throw the user an message. Exemple of `in_array`:

```
$extention = 'doc';
$allowed_extensions = array( 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf' );

$mime = 'text/javascript';
$allowed_mime = array( 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12' );

if ( ! in_array( $extension, $allowed_extensions ) ){
    return false;
}

if ( ! in_array( $mime, $allowed_mime ) ){
    return false;
}
```

If you want to check for file size, you can use [`check_upload_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_upload_size), which is also a WordPress method that uses the site upload limit as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"); 
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
$extension = end($temp); 
if (
    (
        ( $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || 
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || 
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || 
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || 
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || 
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    ) 
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) 
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)

) {  

}
```

you can use this condition for your file type